# How to access Oanda's API in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm looking to get the current rate from Oanda's API.  How would I do this in python?  I have the following credentials and everything I have tried so far has been a bust.  The streaming rates will not work as I cannot parse it correctly.  Help here would greatly be appreciated.

```
curl -X GET "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/instruments?accountId=12345&instruments=EUR_USD"
```

Under normal circumstances I could get it to work, however, they require a "Token" to be passed with the call and I have no Idea how to implement that.  Here is what they have in the documentation:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 12345678900987654321-abc34135acde13f13530" https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/accounts
```

(not my access token by the way, its on their site)

Any help would be great!

In addition here is some of the streaming code that I have tried to adapt:

```
import requests
import json

from optparse import OptionParser

def connect_to_stream():
    """
    Environment           <Domain>
    fxTrade               stream-fxtrade.oanda.com
    fxTrade Practice      stream-fxpractice.oanda.com
    sandbox               stream-sandbox.oanda.com
    """

    # Replace the following variables with your personal ones
    domain = 'stream-fxpractice.oanda.com'
    access_token = 'xxxxxxxxx'
    account_id = 'xxxxxx'
    instruments = "EUR_USD"

    try:
        s = requests.Session()
        url = "https://" + domain + "/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD"
        headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                   # 'X-Accept-Datetime-Format' : 'unix'
                  }
        params = {'instruments' : instruments, 'accountId' : account_id}
        req = requests.Request('GET', url, headers = headers, params = params)
        pre = req.prepare()
        resp = s.send(pre, stream = True, verify = False)
        return resp
    except Exception as e:
        s.close()
        print "Caught exception when connecting to stream\n" + str(e) 
print resp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for this answer in the future, I found that I can access the API by using Oanda's Python wrapper..